# error while installing php from source

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to install php 5.3.X, while i do make im getting this error
im using centos.

```
ext/mysql/php_mysql.o: In function `php_mysql_do_connect':

/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:965: undefined reference to `_mysqlnd_init'
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:982: undefined reference to `mysqlnd_connect'
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:846: undefined reference to `_mysqlnd_init'
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:855: undefined reference to `mysqlnd_connect'
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:903: undefined reference to `mysqlnd_connect'
ext/mysql/php_mysql.o: In function `zif_mysql_fetch_lengths':
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:2266: undefined reference to `_mysqlnd_fetch_lengths'
ext/mysql/php_mysql.o: In function `zif_mysql_escape_string':
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:1811: undefined reference to `mysqlnd_old_escape_string'
ext/mysql/php_mysql.o: In function `zif_mysql_get_client_info':
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:1133: undefined reference to `mysqlnd_get_client_info'
ext/mysql/php_mysql.o: In function `zm_info_mysql':
/root/php-5.3.25/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c:660: undefined reference to `mysqlnd_get_client_info'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1
```

Comment: What OS? Have you install in required *devel libraries? i.e. php_devel, mysql_devel etc

Comment: im using centos 5.4 64bit i have installed mysql_devel

Comment: What about the other devel packages? MySql_devel is the one it appears to be complaining about

Comment: like what other packages ?.

Answer (score 1):

It worked by enchanting make clean command than make and make install.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It also seems that `make clean` is not 100% accurate. Once you fixed your `configure ...`-line, you may want to completely remove the PHP source to apply configure upon.